# How to add GlassFish system libraries

Tags: java, jar, libraries

I accidentally removed the glassfish system libraries from my java build path and could not find a way to add it back.Anyone please help?

Answer (score 9):

You can do this: 
Right click project in **Project Explorer** --> **Properties** --> **Targeted Runtimes** --> ***then click/select your GlassFish targeted runtime displayed*** --> **Apply** --> **OK**

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your project and select "Java Build Path" then go to Libraries tab and click on the button "Add library".
Select server runtime and if you have add a glassfish server on your IDE, you can select it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running on Glassfish 5 and this how I solved the problem : We have to enable JSF 2.3 manually within a Java EE 8 container which has built-in JSF 2.3 support. Just add this class :

```
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.faces.annotation.FacesConfig;

@ApplicationScoped
@FacesConfig( version = FacesConfig.Version.JSF_2_3 ) // JSF activation
public class ApplicationConfiguration {

}
```